# How to generate copies of LinearLayout in java inside loop

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want to know how could I copy a particular LinearLayout like this:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/someID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="520dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/corner_rounder"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

**Inside Java code** using **for** loop. I need such a solution to dynamically generate content depending on its quantity. This LinearLayout is inside ScrollView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Cant do like this!

Try With `RecyclerView` with custom `LinearLayout` and Adapter!

Take a `ArrayList` for indexing `LinearLayout` if you need new `LinearLayout` just programmatically add a value in your `ArrayList` and bang there will be a new `LinearLayout` in your `RecyclerView`and thats how you can add as many as you want !

Answer (score 0):

You should use RecyclerView or ListView. And LinearLayout is a itemview in list.